# What are all the patches that SetPatch applies to Kickstart?

Tags: amiga, operating-system, amiga-kickstart

SetPatch runs as the first command in the Startup-Sequence when Amiga boots up. It applies patches to the code in ROM to fix bugs and also enable features if necessary. For example, I seem to remember that the advanced fetch modes for Chip RAM DMA under AGA only get enabled by SetPatch and/or IPrefs.

Is there a list detailing exactly which patches each version of SetPatch applies and under which conditions?

Comment: Could be a very long list given the number of OS revisions and number of SetPatch revisions. Perhaps you could narrow the question to one or two specific Kickstart versions.

Comment: When you omit the `QUIET` option, it will list what it has installed.